# How to declare Typescript type based on class property?

Tags: typescript

How to create type based on class property ?
Here the example this will illustrate the idea. This is how currently we could create a type based on a class property but it only works within a function/method of the class.

```
class A
{
   properties = { name: 'John'}

   getProperty(propName: string): any
   {
       const properties = this.properties;
       type propertiesType = typeof properties;

       let validKey: keyof propertiesType = 'name';
       let invalidKey: keyof propertiesType = 'age';

       return properties[propName];
   }
 }
```

This code works at the moment but it does not allow us to extract propertiesType on a class level. If this was possible we could write something like the pseudo code example bellow:

```
// Pseudo Code
class A
{
   properties = { name: 'John'}
   type propertiesType = typeof this.properties;

   getProperty(propName: keyof propertiesType): any
   {
      // compile time check for propName validity.
   }
   ...
 }
```

So the question is is there a way to extract a type based on a class property and use this type on a class level ?

Comment: A type can't be declared directly in a class. There is no support for this.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Unfortunately yes but any idea for a work around?

Comment: You can use a class - namespace merging .. but I am not sure it is a good idea, namespaces are not recommended  anymore, and mixin namespaces and modules is discouraged: https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/PTAEAUGcFMFcBMD2oDCj7QFADsCGBbaSAB1wGNpQBBUAb01EdGgA9jEAnAF1C4E9ilYh0SDuASyIAVAZQC81ANoByYaOgSiygLqYAvpjIAbXJEjU6DJmrFdJ5hbVB5CALlDKAUogAW2ZaAGVowA5tBc4CK2fAAUNgByBNDuANbQfIgAZtQAdDYadtKyAJTuuNh8lsGB+kA

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I have added a possible answer. You are much better then me in Typescript please give some feedback.

Comment: My impression was you wanted the type to be scoped to the class. If you want to put it outside, that can easily be done with a type query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling a bit this is the only working approach I have found. Please evaluate if you find any flows or improvements you are welcome to share.

```
type availableKeys = keyof typeof a.properties;

class A
{
   properties = { name: 'John' }

   getProperty(propName: availableKeys): any
   {
      type x = typeof A;
      return this.properties[propName];
    }
  }
}
let a = new A();
a.getProperty('test'); // will give compile time error, only 'name' is allowed.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an index type query to get the type of the property (without an instance as you did in your version of the answer:

```
type propertiesType = A['properties']
type availableKeys = keyof A['properties'];
class A {
    properties = { name: 'John' }

    getProperty(propName: availableKeys): any {

    }
}
```

Comment: Great :) ! This is much more elegant then mine except for the refactoring if for some reason you rename properties editor might not catch it, but in any case I like it a lot.